David Tong's proof that the basis of a tangent space of a manifold is linearly independent
I'm reading David Tong's lecture notes on general relativity. In them (on page 59), as part of the broader proof that $\left.\partial_\mu\right|_p$ is a basis of the tangent space $T_p (M)$ of a manifold $M$ at a point $p$ forms a basis of the tangent space, he proves that this set is linearly independent. I don't understand this proof and would like help comprehending the argument. The proof is as follows:
Suppose we have a vector $\alpha = \alpha_\mu \left.\partial_\mu\right|_p = 0$. Then acting on $f = x^\nu$, this gives $\alpha (x^\nu) = \alpha_\mu \left.(\partial_\mu x^\nu)\right|_p = \alpha_\nu = 0$.
First off, isn't $\alpha = \alpha_\mu \left.\partial_\mu\right|_p = 0$ invalid summation notation? Shouldn't this be $\alpha = \alpha^\mu \left.\partial_\mu\right|_p = 0$? On page 57, Tong states "any equation with two repeated indices that are both up or both down is necessarily wrong".
Then, if we've chosen $\alpha = 0$, doesn't this imply that $\alpha^\mu$ (or maybe $\alpha_\mu$) is necessarily 0? I suppose it could alternatively imply that $\left.\partial_\mu\right|_p=0$ (or some combination where at least one of them is 0 for each value of $\mu$), but I'm not even sure what that would mean since it's not actually acting on anything at this point.

Yes, it looks like you are following a badly-written text. There are many well-written textbooks on differential topology and differential geometry you can use as an alternative.

I take the tangent space at a point to be the set derivations at a point $p\in M$. That $D_p$ is a derivation at a point, if it is a $\mathbb R$-linear map $C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for all $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$:
$$D_p(fg)=f(p)D_pg+(D_pf)g(p)$$
Note that if $f(p)=g(p)=0$, then $D_p(fg)=0$. Moreover, if $f=c$ is constant then $D_pf=0$
To show that $(\partial_i|_p)$ is a basis, you do this in a chart $(\phi,U)$ around a point $p$, and use the fact that $D_p\phi:T_pM\rightarrow T_{\phi(p)}\phi(U)$ is an isomorphism. The tangent vectors $\partial_i|_p$ are explicitly defined via $D_{\phi(p)}\phi^{-1}(\partial_i|_{\phi(p)})$, where $\partial_i|_{\phi(p)}$ is the derivation at a point in $\mathbb R^n$. If $q=(q^1,\dots, q^n)$ is any point in $\mathbb R^n$, then it suffices to prove that $\{\partial_i|_q\}_{i=1}^n$ are a basis for this vector space.
They are linearly independent because if $a^i\partial_i|_q=0$, then for all coordinate functions $x^j:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ sending $(x^1,\dots, x^n)\mapsto x^j$ we have that $a^i\partial_ix^j=a^j=0$.
To show they span, let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. By Taylor's theorem, we can write (in a small neighborhood of $q$):
$$f(x)=f(q)+(\partial_if)(q)(x^i-q^i)+(x^j-q^j)(x^k-q^j)\int_0^1 (\partial_j\partial_kf)(q+t(x-q))dt$$
Now note if $D_q:C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a derivation at the point $q$ then $D_q$ annihilated the the third term as if $I(x)$ is the integral then $(x^j-q^j)I(x)$ and $x^k-q^k$ both vanish at $x=q$. Also, $f(q)$ is constant so $D_q$ annihilates the first term as well. It follows that:
$$D_qf(x)=(\partial_if)(q)D_q(x^i-q^i)$$
Set $D_q(x^i-q^i)=a^i$, then it follows that:
$$D_qf(x)=a^i(\partial_i f)(q)=(a^i\partial_i)|_qf$$
Since $f$ was arbitrary, we have that this holds for all $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, hence $D_q=(a^i\partial_i)|_q$ for some $a^i\in \mathbb R^n$, hence the set $\{\partial_i|_q\}_{i=1}^n$ spans the tangent space of $\mathbb R^n$ at $q$ as desired.

'$\alpha=\alpha^\mu \partial_\mu|_p=0\Rightarrow \alpha^\mu=0$' is exactly the definition of linear independence (which is what we are proving here), so you can't assume that. Here is a trivial example to illustrate what Prof. Tong means. Just consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let
$$\alpha=\alpha^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}+\alpha^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}=0$$
You act $\alpha$ on $x^1$ and you necessarily get
$$\alpha(x^1)=\alpha^1\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^1}+\alpha^2\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^2}=\alpha^1=0$$
And similarly you get $\alpha^2=0$ by acting $\alpha$ on $x^2$. This shows that $\partial / \partial x^1$ and $\partial / \partial x^2$ are linear independent.
Just don't use Prof. Tong's notes for maths. There are a lot of better textbooks. The physics parts of his notes are always excellent, but not the pure maths parts.
